# How many rows can you have when using checksum as primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How many rows can you have when using checksum as primary key?

Comment: Using a checksum as a primary key is a terrible idea, because a checksum is, *by definition*, not unique. Moreover, you have no control over collisions, so you don't even know which rows won't go together, completely independently of how many rows you could expect to store. You can create indexes on checksum values, but don't make them unique.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert is absolutely right. Can you give us few row examples of your table?

Answer (score 1):

`CHECKSUM` returns `int`, so teoretically you can have 2^32 = 4294967296 unique values. 
But in real life you'll never reach that number, as checksum can return same result for different arguments. 
And for this reason you should never use checksum result as PK.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use checksum as primary key since they are not unique. Create a normal auto-increment PK, a checksum column and add an index to it if you need.

Here is why: hashes are subject to collision. Collision is when 2 different inputs result in the same hash. <s>It is unlikely to happen, but chances are.</s> For example, CRC32 for a file with the text "plumless" is exactly the same for the text "buckeroo". Same for "coding" vs "gnu".

When you get around 250.000 rows, chances of collision, therefore duplicate PK, will get considerably high for you.

Sources

- http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/
- http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed/145633#145633

Comment: "unlikely to happen" - Depends on what sort of data you're feeding into `CHECKSUM` - e.g. if you're just feeding in, say, two `INT`s and they're likely to be low values, collisions are quite likely. On my machine, `select CHECKSUM(4,0),CHECKSUM(0,64)` produces 64 for both expressions.

Comment: `CHECKSUM` actually uses a terrible algorithm that is very likely to produce collisions in common instances. Damien's example is just one of many. Using a properly vetted checksum (like `HASHBYTES('sha1', ...)`) improves matters, though it doesn't fix the underlying problem.